# Error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. -WP 7.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I have a demo program in `windows phone 7.1 application`. but When I was running this application the emulator shown an error message as

**The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.**

What might be the issue?

Comment: When did you get that message? Before deployment? After? After running?

Comment: @Toni Before Deployment, While running in studio application showing "Deployment failed" message in output pane and after this message shows the above error in error message box.